# Can asset bundles be categorized on android? (I use unity 5.6 )

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have several asset bundles in my game such as several maps, several levels, several weapons and etc that these can be downloaded gradually after installing game.
Now I want to load all the asset bundles of the weapon in the list of weapons in my game.
Can save all asset bundles of the same type in a specific path and load all the asset bundles in that path (in android platform)?
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an asset bundle for each category. Just put all the weapons in the weapons asset bundle. Then, when you just need to load the weapons, just download and load the weapons asset bundle.